# Using a COUNT in a WHERE Clause to find Products Purchased By One Customer

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, where-clause

I have a PostgreSQL query similar to the following:

```
SELECT product, customer, COUNT(customer)
FROM table
WHERE COUNT (customer) = 1
```

I want the query to return a list of products that have only been bought by one customer. How can I do this without using a COUNT in there WHERE?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see.  You want products purchased by only one customer.  The idea is:

```
SELECT product, MAX(customer) as customer, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY product
HAVING MIN(customer) = MAX(customer);
```

Because there is only one customer, `MAX(customer)` is that customer.  `COUNT(*)` is the number of products the customer purchased.

Answer (score 0):

You must group by product and use a `HAVING` clause where you check if the product has been bought by only 1 customer:

```
SELECT product, 
       MAX(customer) AS customer -- you may remove this column if you don't need the customer also
FROM table
GROUP BY product
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customer) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this, and it unfortunately gave me records for every product and every customer that has ever bought it, but only one record for each product & customer - rather than only returning products that have only ever been bought by a single customer.

Comment: @FaffyWaffle `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customer) = 1` makes sure that the products returned have been bought by only 1 customer. Can you reproduce your problem in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12 with sample data?